# my autocomma just works for the first text input but not the second

Tags: javascript, html

the auto comma just works for the first one but it doesnt work for the second text input, please help me

```
<label>Price Range:</label>
          <label id="my-input">From<input type="text" name="price_range" class="textfield" required="required"/></label>
          <label id="my-input">To<input type="text" name="price_range2" class="textfield" required="required"/></label>
```

the js file 
/* © 2013 aleph-labs.com
 * @author Thanh Tran
 */
      (function () {

/*
     * Add Commas to numbers
     * @method
     * @param  {*} nStr      Numer/String to add comma
     * @param  {String} sep Custom separator in place of the comma
     * @return {String}           The commas-added string
     * @return  String the string of number with commas added
     * @static
     * @author  unknown
     */
    String.addCommas = function (nStr, sep) {
        if (nStr === undefined) nStr = '';
        var parts = nStr.toString().split('.');
        if (!sep) sep = ',';
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
        return parts.join('.');
    };

```
var MoneyInput = {
    value: 0,
    el: null,
    textfield: null,
    max: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    min: 0,


    change: null,


    slider: null,


    create: function(el) {
        return Object.create(this).init(el);
    },


    init: function(el) {
        var _this = this,
            textfield = el.querySelector('.textfield'),
            pattern = /[0-9]/;

        if (el.classList.contains('inited')) return; //do not initialize the wrapper again

        el.classList.add('inited');

        this.min = parseFloat(el.dataset.min) || 0;
        this.max = parseFloat(el.dataset.max) || Number.MAX_VALUE;

        textfield.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
            var inputChar = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
            // console.log(inputChar, e.charCode);

            if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
                //invalid character, prevent input
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        });

        textfield.addEventListener('input', function(/*e*/) {
            _this._inputHandler();
        });

        textfield.addEventListener('click', function(/*e*/) {
            if (!_this.value) {
                textfield.value = '';
            }
        });

        textfield.addEventListener('blur', function(/*e*/) {
            _this._blurHandler();
        });

        this.textfield = textfield;
        this.el = el;
        return this; // for chaining
    },

    _inputHandler: function() {
        var textfield = this.textfield,
            el = this.el,
            str = textfield.value.replace(/,/g, ''),
            invalid = false,
            value = parseFloat(str) || 0;

        if (value < this.min && str) { value = this.min; invalid = true; }
        if (value > this.max) { value = this.max; invalid = true; }
        if (/^0+/.test(str)) {
            //if the text start with zeros
            invalid = true;
        }

        this.value = value;
        this.el.dataset.value = this.value;
        textfield.value = (invalid) ? String.addCommas(value) : String.addCommas(str);
        // console.log(textfield.value, this.value);
        //apply validation highlight for .money-input
        if (this.value) {
            el.classList.add('validated');
        } else {
            el.classList.remove('validated');
        }

        if (typeof this.change === 'function') this.change(this.value);
        if (this.slider && this.slider.setValue) this.slider.setValue(this.value);
    },

    _blurHandler: function() {
        //normalize number input (when there are more . in the strings)
        if (this.value) {
            this.setValue(this.value);
        } else {
            this.el.value = '';
        }
    },

    setValue: function(value) {
        if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
        this.value = value;
        this.strValue = String.addCommas(value);
        this.textfield.value = this.strValue;
        this.el.dataset.value = this.value;
        if(this.value) {
            this.el.classList.add('validated');
        } else {
            this.el.classList.remove('validated');
        }
        // if(typeof this.change === 'function') this.change(this.value);
    },

    getValue: function() {
        return this.value;
    }
};


window.MoneyInput = MoneyInput;
})();

MoneyInput.create(document.querySelector('#my-input'));
```

Comment: Please take care of formatting your code

Comment: i just did that

Comment: Don't see any changes. Still unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll()` instead - your current `querySelector()` only targets the first element found. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: i tried it but then it did not work at all, even the first one